# Open Mapping app like Waze, Google Maps, and Apple Maps (iOS only) From Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, map, salesforce1-platform, mobile-url-scheme

I have requirement :

Add a "Directions" button on the restaurant mobile page,"Directions" button should pass the restaurant's location to the device's selected mapping app.
Once this button is tapped, the **user should be prompted to select their mapping app.**

So Using VF page(Salesforce1) how can i open Mapping app  like **Waze, Google Maps, and Apple Maps (iOS only)** etc ?

For **Skype** we can use **"skype://call?415-555-1212"** URL Scheme.
Regarding Mapping application what will be URL scheme i have need to use?

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

**1.) Waze Map:**

var address = "{!Account.ShippingStreet}, " + "{!Account.ShippingCity}, " + "{!Account.ShippingPostalCode}, " + "{!Account.ShippingCountry}";

var encodedAddress = encodeURIComponent(address);
 sforce.one.navigateToURL("waze://?q="+encodedAddress +"&navigate=yes");

**2.) Apple Maps (iOS only):**

sforce.one.navigateToURL("maps://maps.apple.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr="+encodedlatlong+"&directionsmode=driving");

**3.) Google Maps :**

if (mobileOperSys=="iOS")

sforce.one.navigateToURL("comgooglemaps://?saddr=My+Location&daddr="+encodedlatlong+"&directionsmode=driving");

else

sforce.one.navigateToURL("http://maps.google.com/?saddr=My+Location&daddr="+encodedlatlong+"&directionsmode=transit");